# extract tar then enter its directory (shell scripting)

Tags: shell-script, scripting, tar

How do I make script exctract tar then enter the extracted tar directory?

I was trying

xtract

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -xvf $1 && cd $1
```

Usage example

suppose there's `foo.tar.xz`
so how to use it: `./xtract foo.tar.xz`

So you can see my problem is in argument, I succeed extract it but failed in enter it because of file name extension. So how do i remove it in argument so i can enter `foo` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shell script can never change the working directory for its parent process (the shell invoking the script).  So although you may change to the created directory *in* the script, as soon as the script terminates (and its environment is destroyed, including the fact that a particular directory was the current directory for the process), you will find yourself in whatever directory you were when you executed the script.

However, a shell function executes within the current shell session and may set the current working directory for the session with `cd` in the way that you expect.

The following is a shell function that tries to extract a `tar` archive given on its command line and, if that is successful, changes into the directory provided by the archive's name, with `.tar` removed from the end (this is done using a standard [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)).

```bsh
xtract () {
    tar -x -v -f "$1" &&
    cd -- "${1%.tar}"
}
```

You could define this function by just pasting the above into your shell, or you could add it to wherever you ordinarily add shell functions and aliases, and it would be available in the next shell session you start.

If you want to support `xz`-compressed `tar` archives, you may need to change the above function so that it uses the correct options to `tar` or your system (`-J` or `--xz` with GNU `tar`, for example), or passes the archive from `xz -d -c -- "$1"` via a pipe to `tar -x -v -f -`.  You also have to adjust the `cd` command so that it deletes `.tar.xz` rather than just `.tar` from the end of the given archive's filename.

If you have a smart enough `tar` that uses the filename suffix to determine that compression algorithm correctly, you could get by with

```bsh
xtract () {
    tar -x -v -f "$1" &&
    cd -- "${1%.tar.*}"
}
```

The difference to the previous function is that we're stripping `.tar` followed by a dot and then *any string* from the end of the archive's name to arrive at the directory that we try to `cd` into.